# How to configure Cassandra with Pyramid using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, cassandra, sqlalchemy, pyramid

I've a requirement to develop a web app using pyramid and cassandra in the back end. I've googled enough to find out how to configure cassandra in pyramid (using alchemy scaffold). But, I could not find much details on the same. As per my search, I found that it is not possible to configure NoSQL class databases using alchemy. Is there any way to integrate cassandra with pyramid.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to connect to your cassandra cluster on application start and register the session in the request:

**app.models.__init__.py**

```
def includeme(config):
    def get_session():
        from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
        cluster = Cluster('your.cluster.ip')
        return cluster.connect()
    config.add_request_method(
        lambda request: get_session,
        'dbsession',
        reify=True)
```

**app.__init__:**

```
def main(global_config, **settings):
    config = Configurator(settings=settings)
    config.include('app.models')
```

Then you can you use cassandra session in your view by calling `request.dbsession`, for example like this:
`request.dbsession.execute('SELECT name, email FROM users')`

Answer (score 0):

At the moment **using SQLAlchemy with Cassandra is not possible** cause SQLAlchemy generates [SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) code and Cassandra queries are build in [CQL](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/cql/CQL.html).

About connecting Pyramid with the Cassandra database I have an example similar to the one posted by @matino but also includes a finished callback, so all connections are closed at the end of the request.

Example of my **app.__init__.py**:

```
from cassandra.cluster import Cluster
from cassandra.io.libevreactor import LibevConnection

def main(global_config, **settings):
  """
  ... MORE CONFIG CODE ...

  """

  # Retrieves connection to Cassandra (Non SQL database)
  def get_cassandra(request):
    cluster = Cluster(['127.0.0.1'], port=9042)
    cluster.connection_class = LibevConnection
    def disconnect(request):
        cluster.shutdown()
    session = cluster.connect('app')
    session.row_factory = dict_factory
    request.add_finished_callback(disconnect)
    return session


  config.add_request_method(get_cassandra, 'cassandra', reify=True)

  """
  ... MORE CONFIG CODE ...

  """
```

It certainly works although to be honest I don't know if this is the best approach cause every single time we execute a statement:

```
request.cassandra.execute('SELECT * FROM users')
```

it will go through the whole process: Creating the cluster, defining connection, connecting, executing statement and shutting down the cluster.
I wonder if this is the better approach...